# Cannot convert value of time 'Int' to expected argument type 'NSPropertyListReadOptions' in Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, xcode7

I'm upgrading my existing code to Swift 2, and I need some help with the saving of a Plist file

This code was working in Xcode 6.3, but now with Xcode 7 and Swift 2 it shows me this error:

> Cannot convert value of time 'Int' to expected argument type
>   'NSPropertyListReadOptions' (aka 'NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions')

```
var resultValue = "Value goes here"


@IBAction func saveNote(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Save note to plist
    var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var pathForThePlistFile = appDelegate.plistPathInDocument

    // Extract the content of the file as NSData
    var data:NSData =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(pathForThePlistFile)!
    // Convert the NSData to mutable array
    var notesArray = (try! NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data, options: Int(NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves.rawValue), format: nil)) as! NSMutableArray
    //

    notesArray.addObject(resultValue)
    // Save to plist
    notesArray.writeToFile(pathForThePlistFile, atomically: true)
}
```

Please HELP!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need to convert the options parameter to an Int, it should take a value of type NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions:

```
var notesArray = (try! NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data, options:NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves, format: nil)) as! NSMutableArray
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot define yourself option by your own apple development have some rules and the  already  told that  you can only use 2 option property. For your Understanding i am linking up the  documentation  of [NSropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions)  please  read it carefully and you will understand how to do that

Either you can use

```
NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions
```

either

```
NSPropertyListReadOptions
```

or nil

int will not be supported here